# IS SUBSET-SUM in P if b(the sum) is given in unary and a1,...,an is in binary?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np, decision-problem, polynomial-time

The SUBSET SUM decision problem consists of poitive integers a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>; b. 
We wish to know if for some subset S of the indices, $\sum_{i \in S}a_i = b$

I want to prove that if b is given in unary(and the a<sub>i</sub>'s are gives in binary), that this decision problem is in P

Comment: Use dynamic programming.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution

Answer (score 0):

Start by initializing a boolean array $T$ with indices from $0$ to $b$, inclusive. $T_0$ starts as true (because you can always achieve a sum of 0) and the rest of the array starts as false.

For each value $a_i$, we update the array by going though each value $x$ where $x+a_i\leq b$, and setting $T_{x+a_i}$ to true only if $T_x$ is true.

Essentially, at any point, the array describes which sums are possible using only the values of $a$ which have already been looked at. When a new $a_i$ is looked it, any value that can be made by adding $a_i$ to a currently possible sum becomes possible.

The final decision simply involves checking if $T_b$ is true.

The bulk of the program involves iterating over all $n$ values of $a$ and all $b$ elements of the array, for a total runtime of $O(nb)$. The size of the input is at least $n+b$, because it describes each value of a $a$, and $b$ is written in unary.

Because $O(nb)$ is polynomial with respect to $n+b$, the described problem can be decided in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with multiple numbers involved. You want an algorithm that is polynomial in one of the numbers, and the logarithm of the other numbers.

In this case, since the $a_i$ are all positive, they must all be <= b, otherwise there is no solution. So the values of all the numbers are severely restricted, and an obvious pseudo-polynomial algorithm turns out to be polynomial because b is written in unary.

If we allowed the $a_i$ to be negative, then they wouldn’t be limited to the size of b. Actually if we allow just one negative $a_1$ then we can subtract b from $a_1$ and set b to 0, and change b to binary (since the sizes of 0 in unary and binary are both 1). Then add b to $a_1$ and set b to its original value, in binary, and get an NP-complete problem.